# Table borders aren't appearing?

Tags: html, css

Here's my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Credit Balance</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="idInput">Account </h1>
    <table>
        <thead>
         <tr>
             <th>Balance</th>
             <th>Charges/Credits</th>
         </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td id="balance">filler</td>
                <td id="chargeCredit"> filler</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script src="accountprompt.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's the CSS

```
h1 {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: 500;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,
td {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

I've tried deleting my CSS or JS, but I can't get the borders to return... when I went to bed last night I swear it was working fine, but I must have edited something and gone to bed!

Comment: Your code shows a table with borders for me.

Comment: clear your browser cache and reload

Comment: As Fabrice Fabiyi pointer out clearing my cache and using another browser got it working, I guess this goes to show I should be more diligent about checking other browsers, and I had no idea that your cache could mess with stuff like that.  Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When I went to https://jsfiddle.net/6a0opv7d/ and put your code, I saw the borders. Maybe you need to clear your cache and reload. That can be done by doing Shift + F5 on Windows. Or make sure that your CSS is linked properly, although all the other CSS is working.

```
    table, th, td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
```